# Update in the same column from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to update a column in my table that was ignored at the initial insert based on a key and not null values in the same column.

My table is a history table in a data warehouse : it consists of (to simplify):

- id which is its primary key
- employee_id
- date_of_birth
- project_id

The rows help the company keep track of projects that an employee had worked on.

The problem is that when updating this table, the date_of_birth column is ignored, which is a problem for me since I'm working on a project that needs the age of the employee at the time he changed projects.

Actual:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+
| ID | EMPLOYEE_ID | YEAR_OF_BIRTH | PROJECT_ID |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+
|  1 |           1 | 1980          |          1 |
|  2 |           1 | NULL          |          2 |
|  3 |           2 | 1990          |          2 |
|  4 |           2 | NULL          |          1 |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+
```

And this what I want:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+
| ID | EMPLOYEE_ID | YEAR_OF_BIRTH | PROJECT_ID |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+
|  1 |           1 |          1980 |          1 |
|  2 |           1 |          1980 |          2 |
|  3 |           2 |          1990 |          2 |
|  4 |           2 |          1990 |          1 |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+
```

Comment: "I want" isn't a question or problem statement. Have you attempted to solve this yourself at all? Where did you get stuck? We like to help here, but we're not so keen on being asked to do the whole job, for free, without (apparently) much effort from the person asking. Luckily this one isn't all that complicated for experienced SQL devs, so people might just chuck an answer out. But for future reference, if you tried something, please show it. If you didn't, then why not? Did you try and find out how you might approach the task?

Comment: Not sure I understand the model with regards to the `YEAR_OF_BIRTH`. Assuming this is the year the employee was born, it should be stored on the Employee table. It should not be possible for the same employee to have two different years of birth, but your model allows this. If you normalize the structure your problem goes away.

Comment: @cf_en it's a history table in a data warehouse - so it's been taken from what is (probably) a normalised database and copied here. So the everyday rules don't apply :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could try using `COALESCE` to conditionally replace a `NULL` year of birth with a non `NULL` value:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    EMPLOYEE_ID,
    COALESCE(YEAR_OF_BIRTH, MAX(YEAR_OF_BIRTH) OVER (PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE_ID)) AS YEAR_OF_BIRTH,
    PROJECT_ID
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query should do what you want:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET YEAR_OF_BIRTH = (SELECT MIN(YEAR_OF_BIRTH) FROM yourTable a where a.EMPLOYEE_ID = EMPLOYEE_ID)
WHERE YEAR_OF_BIRTH IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your sample data, you can also use a correlated subquery as

```
SELECT T1.ID,
       T1.EMPLOYEE_ID,
       ISNULL(YEAR_OF_BIRTH,(
         SELECT MAX(T2.YEAR_OF_BIRTH)
         FROM T T2
         WHERE T2.EMPLOYEE_ID = T1.EMPLOYEE_ID
       )),
       T1.PROJECT_ID
FROM T T1 ;
```

OR

```
SELECT ID,
       EMPLOYEE_ID,
       ISNULL(YEAR_OF_BIRTH, MAX(YEAR_OF_BIRTH) OVER (PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE_ID)) AS YEAR_OF_BIRTH,
       PROJECT_ID
FROM T;
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=95879d9f8f4c75b2f2a56f07d8d6585b)**

Answer (score 0):

I would use an updatable CTE for this purpose:

```
with toupdate as (
      select a.*, min(year_of_birth) over (partition by employee_id) as min_date_of_birth
      from actual a
     )
update toupdate
    set date_of_birth = min_date_of_birth
    where date_of_birth is null or date_of_birth <> min_ date_of_birth;
```

The `where` clause reduces the number of rows being updated.

That said, FIX YOUR DATA MODEL.  Sorry for raising my voice.  The date-of-birth information should not be stored in this table.  It should be in the employee table, because an employee has only one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Your desired output can get by this query:

```
SELECT ID, EMPLOYEE_ID,
    MAX(YEAR_OF_BIRTH) OVER (PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE_ID) AS YEAR_OF_BIRTH,
    PROJECT_ID
FROM Table1
```

To check the output of the query you can **[Click Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c38067bf0f967a3fa37e6bf25e1b4f1f)**